# Mongodb Java - How to return restricted fields with find() or findOne()

Tags: java, mongodb

With the driver Java Mongodb, I am looking for a way to return just restricted fields with a 
`find()` or `findOne()`.
For example, I have a collection `"people"` with fields : `"id"`, `"name"`, `"surname"`, `"address"`, `"city"`... and I just want to return `"name"` and `"surname"`

I searched on the Web and I just found this example of code Java Mongodb : http://vsbabu.org/mt/archives/2010/03/02/simple_mongodbjava_example.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass another DBObject with the names of the fields and pass it here:

```
cur = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("id", 6655), your_dbobject_with_field_names);
```

Here is the [API documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6.1/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: OK that's it, it seems we have to return min. 2 fields...
this.dbcoll = this.db.getCollection("people");
DBCursor cursor = this.dbcoll.find(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("name", "surname"));

Comment: I think you'd do BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("name",1).add("surname",1).get()

Answer (score 43):

If you are using Java Driver 3.1, you can use [Projections](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html):

```
collection.find().projection(Projections.include("name", "surname"));
```

Comment: Thank you. "Projections" before include was missing! +1

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I haven't tried using it against v3.8 but the documentation states the methods exist and I don't think the functionality changed according to docs.

Answer (score 2):

This codes will handle your problem.(java driver 3.0.2)

```
 BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
 fields.put("title", 1);
 DBCursor cursor = collection.find(new BasicDBObject(),fields).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

this code run for me:

```
String json = "{_id:0,name:1,surname:1}";
Bson bson =  BasicDBObject.parse( json );
FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find().projection(bson);
```