# How to run find query with a selected field using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to run following query using mongo java driver

```
db.myCollection.find({},{_id:1})
```

I need all the ids from the collection.
The above query runs fine in mongo client.

But, I need results through my java code.
I tried below **non-working** code.. because, as you can see below I am unable to create
  `{},{_id:1}` for `find()` method from the java driver.

```
BasicDBObject query= new BasicDBObject("","").append("",new BasicDBObject("_id","1"));

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);


try {
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Please advise the appropriate way to initialize `query` object

**Edit:**

I can always get the ids by following:

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
        try {
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next().get("_id"));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

But, still it would be nicer to learn how to create the accurate query object, maybe that would be faster on big (+30gb) dataset as mine. So, I am keeping this question open.

Comment: For MongoDB 3.1, you can use Seb's answer from this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568910/mongodb-java-how-to-return-restricted-fields-with-find-or-findone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your query conditions and selected fields objects as separate parameters to `find`:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "1");
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query, fields);
```

Comment: in mongodb 3.0 driver api, find(BasicDbObject,BasicDbOject) method no longer exist.

Comment: `projection()` method has been added, that can be used to return a subset of fields, in 3.0+ versions.

Comment: And to piggyback @yashgarg1232, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30699216/1422451) for latest 3.0+ versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can project fields from a collection as shown below.

```
// Create query and fields
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();

// Assign 1 or 0 for projecting a specific field.
fields.put("_id", 0);
fields.put("Student ID", 1);
fields.put("Student Age", 1);
fields.put("Gender", 1);

// Pass query and fields to find()
DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query, fields);
```

Comment: welcome @Arun, could you fix the code formating, and explain a bit more your answer? :)

Comment: ... especially the query and cursor have no meaning in this example - it is now a complete answer.

Comment: This question talks about what you must do in 3.1 and later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568910/mongodb-java-how-to-return-restricted-fields-with-find-or-findone

Answer (score 1):

```
Below snippet gets all documents where “firstName” is “Gopi”.
<pre>
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("firstName", "Gopi");

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;

public class FindDocument {

    /* Step 1 : get mongoClient */
    public static MongoClient getMongoClient(){
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
         try {
             mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return mongoClient;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MongoClient mongoClient = getMongoClient();

        /* Step 2: Connect to DB */
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("sample");

        /*Step 3 : Get collection */
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("employee");

        /* Step 4 : Create Query object */
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("firstName", "Gopi");

        /* Step 5 : Get all documents */
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);

        /* Step 6 : Print all documents */
        while(cursor.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }

}

</pre>



Output

{ "_id" : 3.0 , "firstName" : "Gopi" , "lastName" : "Battu"}
```