# Mongodb get specific field for java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I have a collections named as users and I want to get specific entry which is latitude and longitude. In mongodb shell, I achieved to get my desired result by typing that;

```
db.users.find({},{latitude:1,longitude:1})
```

But in java, I failed. What I have done in java is that;

```
List<Document> results = db.getCollection("users").find(eq("latitude":1,"longitude",1))
```

So, does anyone has an idea to solve this ?

here is my collection's structure;

> {
>           "_id": "2",
>           "username": "**",
>           "password": "**",
>           "firm": "SpringSource",
>           "roles": [
>               "client"
>           ],
>           "items": [
>               {
>                   "_id": "030b0b88-9b9b-4886-b78e-32ec8cd0abe9",
>                   "item-id": "1111",
>                   "item-name": "Tea latte",
>                   "price": 11111,
>                   "quantity": 11
>               },
>               {
>                   "_id": "b320d345-630f-4068-8b50-63313b7d201b",
>                   "item-id": "2222",
>                   "item-name": "Mint Tea",
>                   "price": 2222,
>                   "quantity": 2222
>               },
>               {
>                   "_id": "d51e5391-5741-4d33-a481-4139df4ffa0e",
>                   "item-id": "3333",
>                   "item-name": "Black Tea",
>                   "price": 3333,
>                   "quantity": 33
>               },
>               {
>                   "_id": "961f52a3-d0d3-45e9-a1cb-475d2c9b272f",
>                   "item-id": "4444",
>                   "item-name": "Green Tea",
>                   "price": 4444,
>                   "quantity": 444
>               }
>           ],
>           "latitude": "39.909062",
>           "longitude": "32.778401"
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "3",
>           "username": "**",
>           "password": "**",
>           "firm": "RedHat",
>           "roles": [
>               "client"
>           ]
>       },
>       {
>           "_id": "1",
>           "username": "**",
>           "password": "**",
>           "firm": "SpringSource",
>           "roles": [
>               "admin",
>               "client"
>           ],
>           "items": [
>               {
>                   "_id": "79c35305-54d1-477e-957d-782f4bf2145a",
>                   "item-id": "11111",
>                   "item-name": "Americano",
>                   "price": 111,
>                   "quantity": 11
>               },
>               {
>                   "_id": "5c7e03eb-1fde-4932-a2bc-94a2f002b382",
>                   "item-id": "2222",
>                   "item-name": "Filter Coffee",
>                   "price": 2222,
>                   "quantity": 22
>               },
>               {
>                   "_id": "a413c06c-4242-4b30-80a9-62e7d7b84fb3",
>                   "item-id": "3333",
>                   "item-name": "tea",
>                   "price": 33333,
>                   "quantity": 44444
>               }
>           ],
>           "latitude": "39.877619",
>           "longitude": "32.682537"
>       }

Comment: Your java statement doesn't look like valid Java due to that semicolon. Is it a compile error, or what?

Comment: Please explain exactly what happens when your code runs.

Comment: @Steve11235 actually, Its a restful api call so I do not compile code but When I make restful GET call, it returns anything.

Comment: @Compass semicolon is forgotten in comment but it exists in java code. Basically, my problem is finding equal statement of shell command in java. Shell command is  "db.users.find({},{latitude:1,longitude:1})  " .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568910/mongodb-java-how-to-return-restricted-fields-with-find-or-findone projections solved my problem.